# Meaning of the Symbol @@ in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the meaning of the symbol `@@` in SQL Server?

Comment: `Global variable names begin with a @@ prefix`

Comment: Global variables in SQL server cannot be defined, but instead are maintained by the server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In SQL Server, symbol `@@` is prefixed to global variables.

The server maintains all the global variables. We cannot declare them.

Answer (score 17):

> Global variable names begin with a `@@` prefix. You do not need to
>   declare them, since the server constantly maintains them. They are
>   system-defined functions and you cannot declare them.

See  Reference  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39131/Global-Variables-in-SQL-Server)

[image]

Comment: The list is incomplete, the source you mentioned is not a valid source

Comment: What is invalid about the link? The list is an excerpt as you can clearly see from the missing bottom line.